# useSelector hook returns empty array on page reload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have the following file with a `/properties/details/:id` route.

```
function App():JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>  
          <div className="body-container">
             <Switch>
                <Route exact path={['/', '/home']} component={Home}  />
                //...
                <Route exact path="/properties/details/:id" component={PropertyDetails}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>              
      
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the following is the PropertyDetails component

```
import React from 'react';
import  { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from '../../store/index';
import { Listing } from '../../store/listings/types';
import { Media } from '../../store/listings/types';

const PropertyDetails:React.FC<any> = (props):JSX.Element => {  
  const listings:Listing[] = useSelector<RootState, Listing[]>((state: RootState) => state.listings);
  const id = props.match.params.id;
  const filteredListings:Listing[] = listings.filter((item:Listing) => { 
    if (item.listingId) {
      return item.listingId === id;
    }
  });

  const listing:Listing = filteredListings[0] || { media: []};

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Country : {listing.country}</p>
      <div className="images">
        {       
            listing.media.map((item: Media, index) => { 
            return (<div className="image-container">
              <img key={index} src={item.MediaURL} /> 
            </div>)
            })
          }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default PropertyDetails;
```

I am able to navigate to the above component from the following `PropertyList` component with the `Link` component of `react-router-dom`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropertyItem from '../PropertyItem/PropertyItem';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Card from '../Card/Card';
import './PropertyList.scss';

const PropertyList:React.FC<any> = ({ listings }):JSX.Element => { 
  return (
    <div className="property-list">
      {listings.map((item:any) => (        
        <Link to={`/properties/${item.listingId}`}>
            <Card >
              <PropertyItem key={item.listingId} { ...item}/>
            </Card>
        </Link>        
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PropertyList;
```

This is my action file

```
import { Listing, ListingActionTypes, ListingAction } from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchListings(listings: Listing[]): ListingAction {
  return {
    type: ListingActionTypes.FETCH_ALL_LISTINGS,
    payload: listings,
  }
}

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://api.example.com`,
});

export function fetchListingsData() {
  const url = `/listings?access_token=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`;

  return async (dispatch: { (arg0: ListingAction):void }) => {
    try {
      const res = await axiosInstance({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
      });

      const data = transformResponse(res);      
      dispatch(fetchListings([...data]));
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error); //TODO: handle error
    }
    return 'done';
  };
}

const transformResponse = (res: any):Listing[] => {
  if (res && res.data && res.data.bundle) {
    return res.data.bundle.map((item: any) => {
      const weather = {
        //...
        country: item.Country,        
      };
      return weather;
    });
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};
```

And the following is my reducer

```
import {
  Listing,
  ListingActionTypes,
  ListingAction,
} from './types';


const initialState:Listing[] = [];

export const listings = (state=initialState, action: ListingAction): Listing[] => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ListingActionTypes.FETCH_ALL_LISTINGS:
      if (action.payload) {
        state = [...action.payload];
        return state;
      } else {
        state = [];
        return state;
      }
      
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Using the Link I am able to successfully load the details content. But when I refresh the page, the content disappears. The `useSelector` hook returns an empty array. I am not sure why this is happening. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are calling `fetchListingsData()`. I assume you are calling it on the `PropertyList` component. You need to make sure you are calling that function on the `PropertyDetails` component as well if you don't have the data available.

When you refresh the page, all data in memory is lost and you have to make the call again to get the data.